# Drop down problem with new tab feature

Tags: bug, new-nav

There is a slight bug with the new tab feature.

If you click the arrow inside the currently viewed tab and mouse over the arrows on the other tabs, this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Which browser and version are you using?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers That was the latest version of Safari 9.0.2